# Change a link's href value based on time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm coding a 'Connect to Meeting' page where i would like the link that allows attendees to join our GoToMeeting event to 'become active' 15 minutes prior to the start time.

So the page users visit to see the connection info (meetingID, password) includes the start time of the meeting. I need a button ('Connect To Meeting') to change from inactive to Active when 
`[Now() < (StartTime()-15minutes)]`.

Comment: So what is your question or are you looking for someone to code this for you?

Comment: Kinda hoped to see relevant suggestions in 'Related Questions'. So yeah...looking to see how others have approached the problem. Button state is usually selector-based or result of user events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need the button to change, calculate the difference between now() and your start time and create a settimeout with that value.

```
var now = new Date();
var start = new Date(2010,5,27,11,30,0); // starts at 11:30am
var diff = start.getMilliseconds() - now.getMilliseconds();
window.setTimeout("document.getElementById('button').disabled = false;",diff);
```

Comment: When i started this question my goal was, as you say - to change the button so yep, thankx for the mechanics to that. FWIW, to fire a function makes for much more flexibility.